How to handle merged cell table using pdfplumber
I am trying to parse pdf (including tables) and convert to json.
as of now, i am able to convert a table if it has atleast one row and 2 columns.
but i am struggling to parse a table to json properly if it has a merged cell in it.
for example:

Here if you can see, "Low absolute lymphocyte count (ALC) (see section 4.4)" is a merged cell.
below is my existing block of code.
checking if its valid table or not and then extract.
def is_valid_table(table):
    min_rows, min_columns = 1, 2
    return len(table) >= min_rows and len(table[0]) >= min_columns

def extract_valid_tables(page):
    tables = page.extract_tables({
        "vertical_strategy": "lines",
        "horizontal_strategy": "lines",
        "edge_min_length": 15,
        "min_words_vertical": 1,
    })
    return [table for table in tables if is_valid_table(table)]


# then doing json conversion for each table

valid_tables = extract_valid_tables(page)
            for table in valid_tables:
                table_start_text = "\n".join(["".join(str(cell) if cell is not None else "" for cell in row) for row in table])
                table_start_index = page_text.find(table_start_text)
                table_title = find_table_title(page_text, table_start_index)
                headers = table[0]
                table_data = [dict(zip(headers, [str(cell) if cell is not None else "" for cell in row])) for row in table[1:]]
                pdf_data["tables"].append({
                    "title": table_title,
                    "page_number": page.page_number,
                    "data": table_data
                })

Any help would be highly appreciated, Thanks.

Which is the problem that you are facing? The code results in error? What are the output that you are receiving?

I am looking for some help on parsing pdf file (which has table with merged cells in it, image shown as above) to json.
I was able to parse normal table without any merged cells, above code parses the same.
